# tibble::add_column to grouped dataframe respecting groups

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, tibble

If I do `mutate` after `group_by`, a new column is created which contains the new value g_DP corresponding to the rows in a group.

```
df <- 
  df %>% 
    group_by(Sample) %>%
     mutate(g_DP = sum(g_AD))
```

[image]

However, I'd like to specify where to insert the new column upon creating it, using `tibble::add_column`. When I do this, it just adds the sum of g_AD, without grouping, to all rows.

Ho can I get `add_column` to behave like `mutate` for this purpose?

```
 df <- 
      df %>% 
        group_by(Sample) %>%
          add_column(g_DP = sum(.$g_AD), .after="g_AD")
```

[image]

Comment: `add_column` is from tibble and  `group_by` is from dplyr. The tibble function will not respect the `dplyr` groupings. Why aren't you using `mutate` here?

Comment: I'd like to specify where to insert the new column upon creating it, without having to do `select` afterwards and manually specifying the new order of columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to respect the groups, you need to use a `dplyr` `do()` call

```
df %>% 
  group_by(sample) %>% 
  do(add_column(., g_DP = sum(.$g_AD), .after="g_AD"))
```